# Toggle multiple annotations on and off with buttons using plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I used plotly to create a plot with multiple annotations. This is my code and it works as intended:

```
library(plotly)
a <- 1:10
b <- 1:10
data <- data.frame(a,b)

annotations <- list(x = a[3:4],
                    y = b[3:4],
                    text = c("p1","p2"),
                    showarrow = TRUE)

p <- plot_ly(data = data, x = ~a, y = ~b, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")
p <- layout(p, annotations = annotations)
p
```

[image: This is the plot I get]

But I can't figure out how to properly implement buttons to turn the annotations on and off. My code below implements buttons, but when I use them, only one arrow is shown, that is out of place and has no text.

```
library(plotly)
a <- 1:10
b <- 1:10
data <- data.frame(a,b)

annotations <- list(x = a[3:4],
                    y = b[3:4],
                    text = c("p1","p2"),
                    showarrow = TRUE)

updatemenus <- list(
  list(
    type= 'buttons',
    buttons = list(
      list(
        label = "ON",
        method = "update",
        args = list(list(),
                    list(annotations = list(annotations)))),
      list(
        label = "OFF",
        method = "update",
        args = list(list(),
                    list(annotations = list(c()))))
    )
  )
)

p <- plot_ly(data = data, x = ~a, y = ~b, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")
p <- layout(p, updatemenus = updatemenus)
p
```

[image: The plot looks like this when I use the ON button.]

It would be nice if anyone could help me out here, or show me some alternative way to implement annotations that can be toggled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `for loop` or `lapply`. For example:

```
library(plotly)
a <- 1:10
b <- 1:10
text <- LETTERS[seq(1,10)]
data <- data.frame(a,b,text)

annotations = list()
for (i in 1:length(data[,1])) {
  annotation <- list(x = data$a[i],
                      y = data$b[i],
                      text = data$text[i],
                      showarrow = TRUE)
  annotations[[i]] <- annotation
}

updatemenus <- list(
  list(
    type= 'buttons',
    buttons = list(
      list(
        label = "ON",
        method = "update",
        args = list(list(),
                    list(annotations = annotations))),
      list(
        label = "OFF",
        method = "update",
        args = list(list(),
                    list(annotations = list(c()))))
    )
  )
)

p <- plot_ly(data = data, x = ~a, y = ~b, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")
p <- layout(p, annotations = annotations, updatemenus = updatemenus)
p
```